# Is there a neat way to collapse 3 for loops in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, discord.py

I have this very hacky way of finding all users in a discord voice channel.

```
for guild in self.bot.guilds:
   for channel in guild.voice_channels:
      for member in channel.members:
         self.increment_field(member, 'voice_time')
```

Is there a better way

Comment: Why do you think this is "hacky"? With a nested data strucutre like this, it is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I suggested an alternative that can clean up where the loop is used, but I agree with what others have said. If the problem involves iterating over a triple-nested structure, you'll need a 3D loop or something equivalent. A 3D `for` is as basic and un-"hacky" as it gets though. It's just using a language construct for its intended purpose, and that's perfectly alright.

Answer (score 4):

The times I've wanted to "collapse" a 3D loop like this, I moved it to a generator function, had it `yield` values, then used that generator with a flat `for`-loop later:

```
def gen_the_things():
    for guild in self.bot.guilds:
       for channel in guild.voice_channels:
          for member in channel.members:
             yield member

for member in gen_the_things():
    self.increment_field(member, 'voice_time')
```

This just moves the bulk, but that isn't necessarily bad.

You may need to pass things into that function, or make it an instance method. I kept it simple here for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

This seems quite reasonable to me and not "hacky" at all when you have such a deeply nested data structure.